# Configuring subdomain in NGINX

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I am trying to configure a subdomain in NGINX. Where am I going wrong?

Following is the configuration file:

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name www.teamomattic.com;
rewrite ^/(.*) http://teamomattic.com permanent;

}

server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name teamomattic.com *.teamomattic.com;

    root /home/jclark/web/teamomattic.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/$host-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/dev-error.log error;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        # try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.teamomattic.com;

    root /home/jclark/web/teamomattic.com/images;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/$host-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/dev-error.log error;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: what happens when you make a GET request to the www subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing. I would do it this way.

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.teamomattic.com;

    location / { return 303 http://teamomattic.com$request_uri; }
}
```

- 303 is the new temporary redirect. I never use permanent redirects, b/c you stay flexible and don't need to ask your custormers to clear cache.
- You may not need this location block wrapper and can directly use return in server. But it is best practice to use always location, b/c you can add more locations easily.
- Please use https if possible.
- `request_uri` passes path and query string through - so you don't loose that info.